# how to use ajax response data in another javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working with google map.My map data come from php using ajax response.

My ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mapajax.php",
    dataType:'text',
    success: function (result) {

                console.log(result); 

    }
    });
</script>
```

Now I have need to put my response data in my map `var location`

```
function initialize() {
    var locations = [
      //Now here I put my ajax response result
    ];
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can have a variable outside to set it to but this is also bad practice since this is an AJAX request you dont know when this will complete. Since you are using jquery I'd look into $.when

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to refactor your code a little. I'm assuming you call `initialize` from the success callback.

Pass the `locations` array as an argument to `initialize`.

```
function initialize(locations) { ... }

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mapajax.php",
    dataType:'text',
    success: function (result) {
        initialize(result); 
    }
});
```

Then you can cut down even more and just do `success: initialize`, as long as `initialize` doesn't expect other parameters.

Comment: This works perfectly fine but I prefer to use $.when in these situations as opposed to the success callback. I guess its just a preference thing?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle with an example using $.when but its for SYNTAX only not making the call

http://jsfiddle.net/2y6689mu/

```
// Returns a deferred object
function mapData(){ return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mapajax.php",
    dataType:'text'
});
}
// This is the magic where it waits for the data to be resolved
$.when( mapData() ).then( initialize, errorHandler );
```

EDIT** function already returns a promise so you can just use

```
mapData().then()
```

per code-jaff comments

Comment: you don't need to wrap that function with `when`, simply `mapData().then()` would be enough, since ajax already returns the promise.

Comment: Thanks you are correct! I did not realize you could do that actually

Answer (score 0):

This is done using callbacks, http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/ , here's a link if you want to read up on those. Let's see your current code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "mapajax.php",
dataType:'text',
success: function (result) {
    console.log(result); 
}
});
</script>
```

As you noticed, the 'result' data is accessible in the success function. So how do you get transport it to another function? You used console.log(result) to print the data to your console. And without realizing it, you almost solved the problem yourself.

Just call the initialize function inside the success function of the ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "mapajax.php",
dataType:'text',
success: function (result) {
    initialize(result); 
}
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is expected `dataType` response from `$.ajax()` to `mapajax.php` call `text` ?

Try

```
$(function () {
    function initialize(data) {
        var locations = [
        //Now here I put my ajax response result
        ];
        // "put my ajax response result"
        // utilizing `Array.prototype.push()`
        locations.push(data);
        // do stuff
        // with `locations` data, e.g., 
        return console.log(JSON.parse(locations));
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mapajax.php",
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (result) {
            initialize(result);
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/maaxoy91/

See

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push